# Get Class Name and Method Name Where Exception Occurred From Exception Details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this Application_Error event in my Global.asax.cs which will get any unhandled exceptions occurred in my application. I was able to get the error message. What I'm trying to get also is the Class name and Method name where exception happened so that it,s easier to trace where and what is the cause of the exception. Please help.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var errMsg = Server.GetLastError().Message;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errMsg)) return;
        //Get Class name and method name
        //ErrorLog.SaveLog(errMsg, Classname, Methodname);
        Context.ClearError();
    }
```

Comment: `var errMsg = Server.GetLastError().StackTrace;`

Comment: [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/AxXPD64S1gw) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can find this information in the call stack, using StackTrace, see the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to log:

```
Server.GetLastError().ToString()
```

This includes the error message and stack trace for the exception and any inner exceptions, and in some cases, other useful information (*).

Note that `Server.GetLastError().StackTrace` will only give you the stack trace of the outer exception, less useful.

(*) By "other useful information", I mean that any Exception-derived class can override `ToString` to add additional information specific to that exception type.  For example, [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) overrides `ToString` to append the `ClientConnectionId`.